# Ability to tag / mark question to later reference

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

I would like to request a feature which allows me to tag / mark certain questions to which I could come back later and answer at length, or just comeback later for reference.

I am not sure if such a feature exists. Please let me know there is.

Comment: You mean like the bookmarks in your browser?

Comment: yeah, something like that.

Comment: There is a star below the downvote button. Click it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Favorite the questions by clicking star (looks like you already knew) and

**Sort by Added** in your favorite list, so you can browse it back with the order you added

https://stackoverflow.com/users/57040?tab=favorites#tab-top

For example, I just marked this question as favorite, so I can check it for later on too

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/139541?tab=favorites#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Click the gray star with a white background under the vote count of the question. It will be saved as a favorite; you can see a list of your favorite questions in your profile page.